# Ajax loading a slider

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, slider

I got a menu `div` and a content `div`

If I put the slider (it's a jquery plugin) in the `index.php` everything works fine, picture below

[image]

But what I want to do is to put every page's content on a different file, for example home page should contain this slider with some basic info, so I put it on home.php

Now as I want to load it I do this:

```
$("#nav_home").click(function(){
    $("#content").load('pages/home.php');
});
```

and here's the part where it crashes, from the slider above it becomes like this:

[image]

HTML:

```
<ul id = "nav"><!-- menu -->
    <li id="nav_home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>    
</ul> 

<div id='content'><!-- content div -->
</div>
```

Comment: which plugin are you using ?

Comment: easy slider 1.5
http://www.swgraphic.com/v2/wp-content/themes/swgraphic/js/easySlider1.5.js

Comment: Where did you write code for slider? If its on the same page where you are loading contents then you might need to initialize slider again on callback of load function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$("#nav_home").click(function(){
    $("#content").load('pages/home.php', 
        function(){
            $("#slider").easySlider({
                auto: true,
                continuous: true 
            });
        }
    );
});
```